# Karma with AngularJS not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, karma-jasmine

I'm using karma and jasmine for unit testing with angular js but it produces the following error.

```
Chrome 54.0.2840 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) LOG: 'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.'

Chrome 54.0.2840 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: window.angular.$$csp is not a function
  at node_modules/angular/angular.js:31768
```

I've attached my karma.conf.js file and the angular module below.

```js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'ng-scenario'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
        './node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        './app/**/*.js',
        './test/logger/loggerControllerTest.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Following is the angular module creation snippet.

```
var app = angular.module("gradchatApp", [
    ngRoute,
    ngAnimate,
    ngAria,
    ngMessages,
    ngResource,
    ngSanitize,
    ngTouch,
    ngCookies,
    angularMoment,
    angularMaterial,
    'ngDialog',
    'infinite-scroll',
    require( 'angular-bootstrap-npm' )
]);
```

Please help me to solve the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to unit test a directive with a separate template (using templateUrl) ?

This happened to me before when I did a mistake in the templateUrl, the template was not found and by default every query not found was redirected to index.html which in turns include angular.js.

Maybe it is the same problem for you ?